# Join consecutive HTML tags of the same kind, same CSS class

Tags: html, xslt, lxml

I am trying to process several HTML files that were automatically generated and I 'm in a situation where I need to join consecutive `span` elements of the same class. The class is more or less known a priori.

**Edit #1:**

**Example input #1:**

```html
<p class='sC8420256'>
  <span class="s32A37344">OPINION EN PARTIE DISSIDENTE COMMUNE AUX JUGES VU</span>
  <span class="s32A37344">Č</span>
  <span class="s32A37344">INI</span>
  <span class="s32A37344">Č</span>
  <span class="s32A37344">, PINTO DE ALBUQUERQUE ET K</span>
  <span class="s32A37344">Ū</span>
  <span class="s32A37344">RIS</span>
</p>
```

**Example input #2:**

```html
<p class="sC8420256">
  <span class="s32A37344">OPINION CONCORDANTE DE M. LE JUGE COSTA, À</span>
  <br>
  <span class="s32A37344">LAQUELLE SE RALLIE M. LE JUGE SPIELMANN</span>
</p>
```

**Notes on the input**

- The `span` elements are all of the same CSS class.
- In most cases no other element apart from `span` is enclosed  in the `<p>` tags. Sometimes though a `span`s *are not consecutive* and a `<br>` or a `<p>` might appear as in Example #2

**Desired output #1:**

```html
<p class='sC8420256'>
  <span class="s32A37344">
    OPINION EN PARTIE DISSIDENTE COMMUNE AUX JUGES VUČINIČ, PINTO DE ALBUQUERQUE ET KŪRIS
  </span>
</p>
```

**Desired output #2:**

```html
<p class="sC8420256">
  <span class="s32A37344">OPINION CONCORDANTE DE M. LE JUGE COSTA, À LAQUELLE SE RALLIE M. LE JUGE SPIELMANN</span>
</p>
```

I can work around this with python and `BeautifulSoup` but is there a quick and dirty method to do the same with XSLT? I am totally clueless when it comes down to XSL...

Comment: Please post your input **as code**, not as a picture - and add the expected output (also as code). -- In your example, **all** span elements have the same class, so that's not very helpful.

Comment: @michael.hor257k You 're right, see my edits above

Comment: Also the precise class names is not important to me. It is also part of the problem definition that the ``span`` elements have the same class

Comment: No, the class name is not important. What **is** important is knowing what the possible scenarios are. If a <p> can contain <span>s of more than one class, your example should show that.  Also, you speak of consecutive spans: is there a scenario where spans of the same class are NOT consecutive? If yes, let us see an example of that, too.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have seen at least one example where the ``span`` tags are not consecutive but every time they are of the same class. See another example in my edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <span class="{span[1]/@class}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="br">
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your first example, will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p class="sC8420256">
  <span class="s32A37344">OPINION EN PARTIE DISSIDENTE COMMUNE AUX JUGES VUČINIČ, PINTO DE ALBUQUERQUE ET KŪRIS</span>
</p>
```

When applied to your second example (after closing the `<br>` element!), the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p class="sC8420256">
  <span class="s32A37344">OPINION CONCORDANTE DE M. LE JUGE COSTA, À LAQUELLE SE RALLIE M. LE JUGE SPIELMANN</span>
</p>
```

**Notes**:

1. You cannot have an unclosed `br` tag in an XML document;
2. I assumed that a `br` needs to be transformed to a space;
3. You did not provide an example where a `p`  appears as a sibling
   of the `span`s, and I don't know how it needs to be handled.

---

> how to write the stylesheet so that the transform retains the rest of
>   the HTML body?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <span class="{span[1]/@class}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="br">
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer it works. You are right of course the HTML has to be transformed to XHTL first. May I ask you however how to write the stylesheet so that the transform retains the rest of the HTML body? Is it too generic to answer? Do you need the XPath to the ``p`` element? My bad I should have clarified that what I display here is an excerpt